# Авторизация и сессии при помощи php + ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Пишу дипломную задачу и появился вопрос в связке `php` и `ajax`.
Я уже сделал БД, написал верстку логин-пейдж, скрипт php для проверки хешированных паролей. Аяксом отправляется запрос `php-скрипту`, сверяется логин и пароль, отправляется обратно на форму ответ типа "да-нет". Это всё работает.

Но совершенно не могу разобраться, как реализовать сессии с `php` и аякс.
С какой стороны вообще подходить.
Во всех примерах в интернете используется по сути чисто php во всех страницах.
Но когда просто сидишь на странице (какой-нибудь в сети), в адресной строке нет расширения страницы типа `index.php`.
Но я не о том, чтобы убрать расширение и верстать через php-страницы. Я хочу использовать `php-скрипты` лишь в связке с аякс-запросами.
Допустим, сверили пароль, перешли на какую-нибудь `/mainpage.html`.
Перед тем, как переходить, нужно ведь сверить правильность сессии? Тот ли человек залогинелся? Иначе по сути можно просто не логинется и совершить переход на `/mainpage` через адресную строку.
Короче, ясно, что я тут плыву. Наверняка чушь полнейшую написал.
Если поняли мысль, дайте ссылок на материалы по этой теме.

Comment: [ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php) из области очевидных

Comment: проверять залогиненность надо не перед переходом, а на самой странице. Естественно, если у вас чисто статические html-страницы, то ни о каких сессиях тут и речи быть не может.

Comment: @teran спасибо за ссылку. А какой подход использовать? Какой подход используют все остальные большие и не очень сайты? Писать в код файлах с расширением .php, в нём же и делать вёрстку?

Comment: нормальный код никогда не смешивает php-код и верстку. для их разделения обычно используют различные шаблонизаторы как [Smarty](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/smarty/info) или [tag:Twig]. В php-файле ваша задача обработать логику, в данном случае, проверить авторизован ли пользователь. Если да, то показать шаблон, если нет, то вероятно вывести какой то из `4xх`- кодов, или перенаправить на страницу авторизации.

Comment: @teran ну я так и думал, что такая разбивка на бек-энд и фронт-энд и должна быть. То есть либо использовать таким образом (с .php), либо разные шаблонизаторы?

Comment: и нахрен нужен будет такой специалист, который для решения банальной задачи тут тусует???? мне кажется, вам оптимальнее задать вопрос тута - https://www.u-mama.ru/forum/kids/schoolboy/

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/session.idpassing.php

Сессии в **PHP** работают или через `uri` - параметор или через `cookie`.
В большинстве стандартных конфигураций это `cookie`.  `Cookie`, если их не трогат на стороне клиента, отправляються **всегда** со всеми запросами на **данный домен**.

Т.е. Каждый **AJAX** запрос или любой другой запрос на то же домен будет содержать id сессии. Если вы не делали каких то странных манипуляций.

Если у вас настроен **PHP** использовать `uri`. То всегда надо передавать `id` как дополнительный параметр. Если пользуете jQuery то можно через https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/ добавить его ко всем запросам.

ПС:

По сути вы таким образом созадёте API. И привязывать его таким образом не совсем правильно. Вы заставляете потребителя API зависить от вашей внутринней реализации этого API. Что будет API переедет на node,go... ?  Лучше посмотреть в сторону JWT(https://jwt.io/) например.